# How to Handle Run-time memory allocation bad pointer error in C Programs (not C++)?

Tags: c, pointers

if is it possible run-time bad pointer exception in C language?.

I am using below compiler.

**Note** **:** **Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler**

Sample Programs Below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Windef.h>

typedef struct tagTest{
int i;
char *str;
}   Test, 
    FAR *LPTest, 
    FAR **LLPTEST;

 extern LLPTEST m;

 int main()
 {

  int i;

  LLPTEST m = NULL;

  m = (LLPTEST)malloc(sizeof(LLPTEST));

  // Here We Check m[0] memory allocated or not ?
  // example: if(m[0]), or if(m[0]->i) any other idea. here m[0] is CXX0030 error expression cannot be evaluated.

  /* allocate memory */
  for(i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
     m[i] = (LPTest) malloc(sizeof(Test));
     m[i]->i = i;
     m[i]->str = (char*) malloc(10*sizeof(char));
     m[i]->str = "Test";
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: By making sure you don't use bad pointers?

Comment: What's *run-time bad pointer exception* ?

Comment: C doesn't have exceptions. So you'll need to make it clear what you are referring to.

Comment: Please Read comment in programs\.

Comment: You need to check if `malloc` returns NULL, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Whether your `malloc` worked is the least of the problems with this code. You're allocating space for a (single) pointer-to-pointer, storing that in a pointer-to-pointer, then trying to iterate through 10 times that memory...

Comment: `sizeof(LLPTEST)` should be `10*sizeof(LPTEST)`

Comment: I do not used 10*sizeof(LPTEST). becuase it is my sample example. my source code i do not know how many number of malloc used?

Comment: @VijayKumbhani That comment does not make any sense. Write in intelligible English or do not write at all.

Comment: Also, [you must not cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: MSVC has SEH. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. C doesn't support exceptions, so there's nothing to catch. What you're seeing isn't a "bad pointer exception," it's a memory access error -- there is no way to recover from it.

Answer (score 3):

You have several problems in your code. Here's a list of some of them:

- [Don't cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- For `m` you allocate `sizeof(LLPTEST)` bytes, but you should really allocate `sizeof(LPTest)`
- Continuing the previous point, you only allocate *one* pointer, so only `m[0]` is valid, all other indexes will cause you to write out of bounds. You should do e.g.

  ```
  m = malloc(sizeof(LPTest) * 10);
  ```

  This point is the cause of your problems, as it causes [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)
- You allocate memory for `m[i]->str`, but then you overwrite that pointer with a pointer to a string literal, thereby loosing the pointer to the allocated memory (i.e. you have a memory leak)
- Continuing the previous point, because `m[i]->str` now points to a string literal, and not something you allocated yourself, you can not `free` this pointer
- No error checking, remember that `malloc` can fail

If you don't know how many items you need to allocate for `m` beforehand, you can use [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) to reallocate with a larger size.

Answer (score 0):

Some exceptions can catch MSVC is to extend the syntax.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct tagTest{
    int i;
    char *str;
} Test;

int main(){
    Test *m;
    //m = malloc(sizeof(Test));//it can be avoided by examining whether NULL simply.
    m = NULL;//malloc is unable to allocate memory
    __try{
        m->i = 0;//exception occurs
        m->str = "Test";
    }
    __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER){
        if(EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION==GetExceptionCode())
            puts("ACCESS VIOLATION");
        puts("EXCEPTION OCCURRED");
    }
}
```